# AngularJS directive for dependant select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to write a directive for dependant select elements. The relationship is `Country > States > Cities`. When element with class `country` get changed I should update element with class `states` and the same behavior for element with class `city`. To get the states I only need the country id and for get cities I need country and state id's. So I did this code:

```
app.directive('country', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.change(function() {
                    $http.get(Routing.generate('states') + '/' + element.val()).success(function(data) {
                        if (data.message) {
                            scope.message = data.message;
                        } else {
                            scope.states = data;
                        }
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (status == '500') {
                            scope.message = "No hay conexión con el servidor.";
                        }
                    });

                    console.log(scope.states);
                    console.log(scope.message);

                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

But `console.log()` statements logs "undefined" I have some questions around this code and the directive I'm trying to build:

1. Why `scope.states` get "undefined" when JSON come with values?
2. How do I access other select element selected option in order to get "cities"?

Note: `app` is a Angular module I have defined

**EDIT**

I rewrite some code and now this is the directive:

```
app.directive('country', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                element.change(function() {
                    $http.get(Routing.generate('states') + '/' + element.val()).success(function(data) {
                        if (data.message) {
                            $scope.message = data.message;
                        } else {
                            $scope.states = data;
                        }
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (status == '500') {
                            $scope.message = "No hay conexión con el servidor.";
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Im my template I have this HTML:

```
<select 
     id="common_commonbundle_standard_address_state" 
     ng-model="common_commonbundle_standard_address.state" 
     required="required" 
     ng-disabled="!states" 
     ng-options="state.name for state in states.entities" 
     tooltip="Estado" 
     tooltip-trigger="focus" 
     tooltip-placement="right" 
     wv-def="Estado" 
     wv-cur="" 
     wv-err="Error!" 
     wv-req="The value you selected is not a valid choice" 
     type="text" 
     class="state ng-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required"         
     var="common_commonbundle_standard_address.country" 
     disabled="disabled">
</select>
```

Why, if I do this `$scope.states = data` and it has values, the select isn't enabled and isn't populated with values?

Comment: most likely your console.log executes before your success function is done.  put the console.log inside the success/error functions.  $http.get returns a promise.

Comment: @MatthewRygiel I made some changes and fix the code, can you take a look at my edit?

Comment: Can you put your code or plunker or similar service so I can see more of your code interactions?

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/annavester/Zd6uX/  It's an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MatthewRygiel since HTML is rendered in server side I don't know how to show this part to you in Plunker :-( and yes I see that example before and use it and it works but I'm trying to create a directive based on that same code you show me

Comment: With directives you will need to have them be able to talk to each other.  Also your directives will most likely need controllers inside of them.  This video shows how to set up communication between your directives.  Hopefully that will help.  https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-communication

Comment: @MatthewRygiel I'll try to make a Fiddle since I can not get this to work, I leave you the link in a few minutes to see if you can help me

Comment: @MatthewRygiel [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oef3hPYo92Q8F4UuDUm4) is it, feel free to ask any doubt

Comment: See if this makes sense.  http://plnkr.co/edit/CwOSFGsq8LcLJdyW2rpl?p=preview

Comment: @MatthewRygiel no, this is not what I'm trying to do, or maybe but not in this way, since info is pulled from DB I just write a example for you to see how or what I have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the comment alluded to, you need to move your console logging inside of your success callback.  that's just the nature of asynchronous requests.

For 1)

```
  $http.get(Routing.generate('states') + '/' + element.val()).success(function(data) {
    console.log('success!');
    if (data.message) {
      scope.message = data.message;
    } else {
      scope.states = data;
    }
    console.log(scope.states);
    console.log(scope.message);
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    if (status == '500') {
      scope.message = "No hay conexión con el servidor.";
    }
  });
```

For 2)
You would want to use whatever is getting set to ng-model