# Set "states" variable cause Error: $rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a select that depends of another select so I'm trying to listen for change event in first select and then populate the second one with values coming from JSON array obtained in server side. Here is the code I build for that purpose:

```
app.directive('country', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.change(function() {
                $http.get(Routing.generate('states') + '/' + element.val()).success(function(data) {
                    if (data.message) {
                        scope.message = data.message;
                    } else {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.states = data;
                        });
                    }
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (status == '500') {
                        scope.message = "No hay conexión con el servidor.";
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

But I'm getting the error as said in post title:

```
Error: $rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress
```

This is  the HTML for the SELECT that I'll change in order to populate the second one:

```
<select 
    id="common_commonbundle_standard_address_country" 
    ng-model="common_commonbundle_standard_address.country" 
    required="required" 
    class="country ng-scope ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required">
    ...
</select>
```

And this is the HTML for the SELECT element I want to populate:

```
<select 
    id="wuelto_common_commonbundle_standard_address_state" 
    ng-model="wuelto_common_commonbundle_standard_address.state"
    ng-disabled="!states" 
    ng-options="state.name for state in states.entities" 
    class="state ng-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" disabled="disabled">
    ...
</select>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please show the full HTML for the `<select>` tag that has the states populated.  You aren't showing how you are setting `ng-options`

Comment: @thescientist the states `<select>` has not values until I change the country `<select>`, that's the dependency. So the idea is to set values in `scope.states = data` where `data` is a Json returned by PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you add $apply?

```
scope.$apply(function() {
  scope.states = data;
});
```

you didn't have that here
[AngularJS directive for dependant select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229872/angularjs-directive-for-dependant-select-element/22232392#22232392)

Take that out.  Typically the only time you would call that is if you were doing DOM manipulation or making requests outside of the context of the Angular framework.

Comment: I did `$apply` because `states` never is updated in controller so second HTML element is never populated and is pretty much the same but slightly different since I wrote more info here, maybe should be good to leave this in the same topic don't know